# Is it possible to remove unused CSS in JS files that Angular generates?

Tags: css, angular, css-purge

I have an Angular application with a lot of CSS. Most of this is written at the component level.

I know that Angular writes the CSS inside the output bundle.

Is it possible to remove unused CSS in this JS file?

After I try `purgecss` I found that it works only on CSS files (`style.scss`), but I was not able to make it work on "CSS in JS" files.

Comment: Did you find a solution since then?